# How to enter password for prompt windows using applescript

Tags: automation, applescript

I'm new to applescript and is currently stuck in access the prompt window asking for my password.

I'm creating a launcher for my daily use application and i want to automate the launching process.

Right now, I'm only launching two application, VirtualHostX and MAMP. Later I might add few some.

Here's what I done so far:

```
tell application "VirtualHostX" to activate
tell application "MAMP" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "VirtualHostX"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Web Server"
                tell menu 1
                    click menu item "Start"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

When launching, It will launch the two application successfully, but Virtual Host will ask me for my password for authorization. I want to integrate entering my password in the flow or code. I already tried to google for answer but failed to find a solution for it.

I can't seem to target that window and enter my password.
[image]

Let me know what am I missing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Password dialogs are shown by SecurityAgent:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "password"
    click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Lauri.

Comment: I think something happened with Yosemite that makes this not work anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For Yosemite, the SecurityAgent dialog box is different. This will work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        set value of text field 2 of window 1 to "yourPassword"
        click button 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```